# Elasticsearch: can't filter on multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to filter a `{ "query" : { "match_all" :{}}}` on elasticsearch but I don't figure it out...

Here's what I send to ES _search method.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/users/location/_search '-H Accept: application/json' '-H Content-Type: application/json'
-d '{
   "query":{
      "match_all":{}
   },
   "filter":{
      "and":{
         "geo_distance":{
            "distance":"500km",
            "location":{
               "lat":48.8,
               "lon":2.33
            }
         },
         "term":{
            "status":1
         }
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "_geo_distance":{
            "location":[
               2.33,
               48.8
            ],
            "order":"asc",
            "unit":"km"
         }
      }
   ]
}'
```

But I always get this error:

```
nested: QueryParsingException[[users] [and] filter does not support [distance]]
```

And if I remove the `"and" :{}` option and only filter on geo_distance, it works...
Any help would be fantastic.

Cheers

Comment: Just change the `and` part to an array. Something like this `and: [{distance:{...}}, {term:{...}}]`

Comment: Why do you need to filter on a `match_all` query?  All it does is return all documents under the users/location index/doc type scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your `and` filter is incorrectly written.  The error states that the `and` filter is having trouble with its parameters, more or less. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/and-filter/

Try this instead:

```
{
   "query":{
      "match_all":{}
   },
   "filter":{
      "and": [
         {
             "geo_distance": {
                "distance":"500km",
                "location":{
                   "lat":48.8,
                   "lon":2.33
                }
             }
         }, {
             "term": {
                "status":1
             }
         }]
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "_geo_distance":{
            "location":[
               2.33,
               48.8
            ],
            "order":"asc",
            "unit":"km"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```